# Web crawler in Rails to extract links and download files from web page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler

I'm using RoR, I will specify a link to a web page in my application and here are the things that I want to do

(1) I want to extract all the links in the web page

(2) Find if they are links to pdf file(basically a pattern match)

(3)I want to download file in link(a pdf for example) and store them on my system.

I tried using Anemone, but it crawls the entire website which overshoots my needs and also how do I download the files in corresponding links?

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) aswell.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.thatwebsite.com/downloads'))

doc.css('a').each do |link|
  if link['href'] =~ /\b.+.pdf/
    begin
      File.open('filename_to_save_to.pdf', 'wb') do |file|
        downloaded_file = open(link['href'])
        file.write(downloaded_file.read())
      end
    rescue => ex
      puts "Something went wrong...."
    end
  end
end
```

You might want to do some better exception catching, but I think you get the idea :)

Comment: This is just what I was looking for to do a small personal project. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [scrapi](https://github.com/assaf/scrapi)? You can scrape the page with css selectors.

Ryan Bates also made a [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/173-screen-scraping-with-scrapi) about it.

To download the files you can use `open-uri`

```
require 'open-uri'  
url = "http://example.com/document.pdf"
file = open(url)  
c = file.read()
```

Comment: But I have trouble using 'scrapi', I'm using ruby 1.8.7. It says              Scraper::Reader::HTMLParseError: Unable to load /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/scrapi-1.2.0/lib/tidy/libtidy.dylib